# Editing SEO related meta tags in SmartEdit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

For configuring the meta keywords and description for our content pages,we are using the keywords and description attributes.
How to make them editable in SmartEdit, as I was not able to view them on SmartEdit?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage tags on page with custom attribute or related item. You can edit new attribute on smartedit. If you are using ootb fields look like keywords, you need to change defaultCmsStructureTypeBlacklistAttributeMap for making it visible.